# Typing in Hebrew with Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm at a loss as to how to make the Hebrew keyboard layout/input work.

The following methods do not work:

1. "Download Hebrew language support. You can do this from the Install/Remove Languages section of "Language Support".

   ```
   System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> "+" -> "Hebrew" -> Add
   System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Keys to Change Layout -> mark [alt]+[shift] 
   (this step is optional, only if you want that custom keyboard shortcut)
   ```

   and
2. `setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,he`

The second option (the code) works for arabic, but not for hebrew.  If I try to set it to hebrew, I get the following error message:
 "Error loading new keyboard description"

Is the shorthand for Hebrew not "he"??  If so, how can I find out what it is?

The first option seems simple, but the available keyboard layouts are unavailable, and the Add button can't be pushed.  I know that the instructions are for Ubuntu, but Lubuntu has a similar enough setup.   (Yes, I've already installed the Hebrew Language Pack).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't switch to anything. (iBus doesn't even show on the system tray, even when clicked to do so).

How can I solve this?

Questions?  Comments?  Criticisms?

Comment: Out of curiousity: did you have the Hebrew layout working with Ubuntu (as opposed to Lubuntu) before?

Answer (score 13):

**This works for other languages as well, just replace the shorthand for your specific language**

**FOR 12.04**

To add the Hebrew language support you have to use:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il
```

**The shorthand for Hebrew is `il`**

To make the change permanent, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

[image]

Enter your password, and click OK.  Once the file open up, add the lone as shown in the image below.  Once done save and exit.

[image]

**FOR 12.10**

Right click on the panel, and click on Panel Settings as shown below.

[image]

When it opens, click on Panel Applets, and then click on Add as shown below.

[image]

Choose Keyboard Layout Handler, and then click on Add as shown below.

[image]

Then high-lite Keyboard Layout Handler, and click on Edit as shown below.

[image]

and then click on add, as shown below.

[image]

Once it opens choose Hebrew, or any other language you desire, and click OK as shown below.

[image]

Once you're done you will be able to switch between layouts from the panel icon, by clicking on it as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am using Lubuntu. I went into preferences and chose Lxkeymap which allowed me to choose Hebrew for my keyboard. Haven't found a keyboard shortcut but I'm glad to be able to type in Hebrew again.

Hope that was helpful. I did download Hebrew language though under; preferences and then language support.