# Arabic keyboard code 12.04

Tags: 12.04, arabic

I saw this [Typing in Hebrew with Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144774/typing-in-hebrew-with-lubuntu/144778#144778) on askubutu.com.

I need to know what the Arabic language keyboard code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arabic language keyboard code is ***`ar`***

To add the Arabic support

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,ar
```

Comment: I thought it should be `ara`, no?

Comment: The display name is ara, but the actual code is ar.

Comment: Both work, but all resource I found mention `ara` for Arabic. May be `ara` is a legacy/old code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3 . Thank you

Comment: The above is not permanent, i have to reenter the above command when i restart ubuntu

Comment: @IbnSaeed What flavor/release of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Mitch 14.04. I just added a keyboard shortcut to enable the keyboard layout after each reboot.