# setxkbmap with alt-shift-toggle option for >1 keyboard layout where layout has name with > 1 word

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am currently trying to set up my system to use two keyboard layouts and switch between with alt_shift. From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144774/typing-in-hebrew-with-lubuntu), I obtained the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il
```

This does exactly what I would like, except that the first keyboard layout that I wish to use is "us 3l" rather than just "us". The existence of a space in the name breaks the command and gives the message "Error loading new keyboard description". I tried escaping the space character, adding quotes around "us 3l", and other such things, but could not get the command to work. I also tried looking up similar such commands but couldn't find any where the layout had a space in it. Note that because of my unusual window manager (awesomewm), GUI solutions generally won't cut it, so a command line solution is preferred.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @guiverc I added the OS version. Adding quotes around "grp:switch... us 3l, il" had the command finish without error but not do anything. Adding quotes around the entire command from the beginning declared that the command was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3l` is a layout variant. Try this:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll -layout us,il -variant 3l,
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you!